# Get name of c function given the filename and the line number - elisp

Tags: c, elisp

I am trying to make a script that tells me all the functions in C codebase that contain a call of of function X.

My strategy is to call rgrep and from te output determine from which functions the searched string is called.

I know little to no lisp so this is an educational experience too for me so please don give answers meaning something along the lines of "USE AWK NOOB"

Comment: AFAIK, `rgrep` is a UNIX command-line appplication.  So what does this have to do with Lisp?

Comment: well i guess since you can run int interactively in emacs, there is an interface with elisp, right?

Comment: So is the question really, "how do I search back from a given line number to the start of the function, and extract the name of the function"?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try cscope?  http://cscope.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

This function worked for finding the function name given that the point is in the function :D

```
(defun search-fun () (interactive)
  (search-backward-regexp "[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*[ \n\t]+\\([a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*\\)[ \n\t]*([^<>=]*)[ \n\t]*{")
  (setq str (match-string 1))
  (if (string= str "if") (search-fun ) (return str)))
```